# Open URL in system browser eg safari,chrome etc instead of mobile app browser?

Tags: html, linkedin-api, deep-linking, html-target

I have a simple link in my app,  user can share this app via post or private message, now I want when the user clicks this link it should open it in sytem browser not linkdein app browser

here is a link in my app

```
document.body.innerHTML += '<br/><br/><br/><br/><p>LinkedInApp TRUEee <a onclick="window.open(this.href,"_system");return false;" href="https://meed.audiencevideo.com/">Visit our HTML tutorial</a>>Open in iBrowser</a></p>'
```

Now when user clicks the link 
'it open the link in linkdein app browser'

What do I need to change to get what I want?

Comment: This is a protocol issue. The ideal approach would be for every app to have its own protocol which you could prefix to a web address in place of `https://` (e.g. `safari::https://` or `fb::https://`) Then any web link could be directed to open in any app that handles `webviews`. We're not there yet, because (for commercial reasons) most apps don't want to simply hand their visitors over to other apps.

Comment: Did you find a way to achieve it? I have the same issue with LinkedIn mobile application

Comment: @alexanoid nope I ended up with another solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't sure that this can be appropriate for you, cuz I'm don't understand the question at all, but I hope this can help you:

May you have a script that disallows new pages being opened.
So instead you can use something like this:

```
 <a onclick="window.open(this.href,'_blank');return false;" href="https://www.w3schools.com/html/">Visit our HTML tutorial</a>
```

Or if you want to use Deep Link from your mobile app, then you have to follow to [this steps](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking).
But in that case why you have tagged this question under #html or #html-target .. You just could add #deep-linking or something like that

Comment: Hi, this still open in the same LinkedIn app browser, I want to open in another browser, not LinkedIn app browser

Comment: As back-end dev, I know only about deep linking. I just came here with seeing attached tags. But as an advice, I think this can help you..
https://medium.com/@ageitgey/mobile-deep-linking-part-2-using-a-hosted-deep-links-provider-c61fa58d083e